# Java inheritance - access private variable / getClass()

Tags: java, inheritance, this

Question: The result of the following code is "5 A" and "10 B". How is it possible that for b.print(), this.num is a reference to a Class A object and this.getClass() is a reference to a Class B Object?

**Superclass A**

```
public class A {
  private int num;

  public A(int num) {
    this.num = num;
  }

  public void print() {
    System.out.println(this.num + " " + this.getClass().getName());
  }
}
```

**Subclass B**

```
public class B extends A {

  public B(int num) {
    super(num);
  }
}
```

**Main Method**

```
A a = new A(5);
B b = new B(10);
a.print();
b.print();
```

Comment: Putting `this.` in front of a method call has no effect.

Comment: They are two different objects, which both get the number they're passed. I don't see why this is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

These are two distinct things.

`this.getClass()` or more simply `getClass()` (as `this` is implied as not specified) will always refer to the actual runtime class that may be the class that uses it or a child of it. If you call it from A, it will return the A class but if you call it from a child of it, it will return this child class.

While `this.num` refers to a specific instance field declared in the `A` class.
 When you code refer to this field, it relies necessarily on the class that declares this specific field.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you call `this` in an instance, you are going to be calling the actual instance, and not the "class". For example, in you case, if you override the method `print` in your class B, like this;

```
public class B extends A {

    public B(int num) {
        super(num);
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("PRINTING B");
    }
}
```

Then when you call the print method it will call this one and not the parent one, even if you use `this.print()` inside any method of the class A

**If you really want to explicitly print the A class, then you need to reference it like this:**

```
    public void print() {
        System.out.println(this.num + " " + A.class.getName());
    }
```